# Using a CheckBox which doesn't exist in current layout

Tags: android

In my application i have a class named **ChatActivity**. Actually it is showing a ListView. In **onCreate** i have set the layout like

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.conversation_window);
```

**conversation_window.xml** looks like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:divider="@null"
android:padding="16dp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:id="@+id/thread_listView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/innerLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#9E9E9E"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#212121"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="(1) 0/158"
    android:id="@+id/character_count_textview"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/compose_editText"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:hint="এখানে লিখুন..."
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/apptheme_textfield_disabled_holo_light"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/send_imageButton"
        android:background="@mipmap/send_black"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

For each row of listView there is another xml called **list_item_chat_message.xml** which looks like this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CheckBox_conversation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentWithBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/in_message_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxWidth="200dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</LinearLayout>
```

There is a CheckBox in **list_item_chat_message.xml** which i want to use in my **ChatActivity** class for **setOnCheckedChangeListener**.But when i am writing like this in **ChatActivity** class

```
itemCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBox_conversation);
```

it throws **null object reference**. So how i can i declare this CheckBox in this activity?

Comment: where you write this code `itemCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBox_conversation)`?;

Comment: in my ChatActivity class

Comment: you should write it and call setOnCheckedChangeListener in your adapter.

Comment: Why don't you set the listener in the list's adapter like everybody else always does

Comment: can you share how your conversation_window layout looks like? Are you including list_item_chat_message.xml in the conversation_window layout or how are your referring to it?

when your calling findViewById it looks for child elements in the given layout (in your case it's the conversation_window), so elements of list_item_chat_message must be included in the xml file or added to the parent layout programmatically.

Comment: @Laszlo Sisa i have now include the conversation_window.xml.

Comment: @pialkanti you need to create adapter class

Comment: @pialkanti
When you call `findViewById(R.id.CheckBox_conversation)` it searches for elements only within the layout set `onCreate()`
I your case this is the conversation_window, from this layout xml I can not see that it explicitly includes list_item_chat_message. You can use the <include> tag for such purpose. Though I can't clearly see how you'd like to connect these two layouts. Some more details on the include tag here:
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include